# how do I implement GetHashCode() when Equals method have or (||) in them?

Tags: c#, data-structures

Consider a class

```csharp
class MyClass {
   int fieldA;
   int fieldB;

   public override bool Equals(object obj) {
       if (this == obj)
           return true;
       if (!(obj is MyClass))
           return false;

       MyClass other = obj as MyClass;
       return fieldA == other.fieldA || fieldB == other.fieldB;
  }
}
```

Two MyClass should be equal when fieldA is equal or fieldB is equal.

Now, I can't find a good GetHashCode() implementation that matches the Equals method I've written. Without reference to other MyClass object to compare to, getting the same hashcode looks like an impossible task, unless I set hashcode to same value and deal with hash collision.

I've written a test case that arbitrarily sets MyClass1 and MyClass2.

```csharp
for (int a1 = 0; a1 \< 3; a1++) {
   for (int b1 = 0; b1 \< 3; b1++) {
      MyClass myClass1 = new MyClass { fieldA = a1, fieldB = b1 };

      for (int a2 = 0; a2 \< 3; a2++) {
         for (int b2 = 0; b2 \< 3; b2++) {
            MyClass myClass2 = new MyClass { fieldA = a2, fieldB = b2 };
            bool equals = myClass1.Equals(myClass2);
            bool hashEquals = myClass1.GetHashCode().Equals(myClass2.GetHashCode());

            if (equals != hashEquals)
               Console.WriteLine($@"Comparing ({a1}, {b1}) with ({a2}, {b2}). Equals: {equals}. HashCode: {hashEquals}");
         }
      }
   }
}
```

If GetHashCode is written properly, there shouldn't be any case where `equals != hashEquals`  hence, nothing should be printed.

I've tried setting HashCode to one of the fields, but realized if another field matches, hashcode would be different.

Comment: *there shouldn't be any case where equals != hashEquals* If you do the math you'll quickly realize this is impossible. There are only 4.29 billion possible hash codes but more than 18 quintillion possible values. Hash codes are not meant to be unique. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/2791540).

Comment: This is impossible. It is only mathematically possible if you had a single static hash number. Consider a value of `(7, 3)` which must match `(7, 4)`. now change the `3` to a `2`. The hash must change yes? Then mathematically you cannot both change the hash which used to match `(7, 4)` but keep the equality to `(7, 4)`

Comment: @JohnWu When I said equals != hashEquals, I meant equals && !hashEquals. Now, this is problematic because when you implement HashSet or Dictionary with the key as MyClass, hashcode will be different, although they are equal to each other.

Comment: If `equals` is true and `hashEquals` is false you have indeed botched your implementation of `GetHashCode()`. Are you asking us to help debug it? If so please share the code.

Comment: So, what you are looking for is a hash code function _f(x, y)_, such that _f(x1, y1)_ is equal to _f(x2, y2)_ whenever either _x1_ == _x2_ OR _y1_ == _y2_.  Did I get that right?  I don't have a clue what that function would look like, but I'm hoping that this comment helps clear up some of the misunderstanding

Comment: I'm almost convinced that it is indeed impossible as maraaa  has said. Hashcode for (7, 3) should match (7, 4) and (5, 3), but not match (5, 4) because you only need to match one of the value to be considered equal. In other words (7, 3) == (7, 5) and (7, 5) == (3, 5), but (7, 3) != (3, 5).

Comment: Knowing both `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` should be linked, my `Equals()` methods are generally limited to calling and comparing `GetHashCode()` for both items. I know that's not helpful for the specific issue of the question, but I think it's a useful reminder because after you solve that problem you'll also be able to greatly simplify the existing `Equals()` code.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn How do you make sure there is 1-to-1 correspondence between every possible state of your object and an int32? Do you e.g. limit the length and the allowed characters of all strings? Isn't that way harder than allowing some unequal objects to have equal hashes after all, which is how the entire thing is designed anyway?

Comment: To meet the rules that all equal instances have an equal hashcode, then the hash must be a constant. `GetHashCode() => 7;` Is it a good hash? no. Should this type be used as a dictionary key? no.

Comment: Your `Equals` method violates rule 3 here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-define-value-equality-for-a-type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition of "Equal" will not work for any hash-based implementation. If A==B and B==C, then A==C must be true, otherwise you get unexpected results in lookups, groupings, and other hash-based algorithms.

In your case, `(1,2)` would be equal to `(3,2)` and `(3,2)` would be equal to `(3,4)`, but `(3,4)` is not equal to `(1,2)`.  If you tried to "group" objects based on equality, you'd get indeterminate results depending on the order in which the objects were compared.

Even if it *did* work, you could not use those values in a hash algorithm, since two objects that are "equal" *must* have the same hash, but objects with different values of `fieldA` *or* `fieldB` can still be equal, so there's no way to define a hash that includes either of those fields. You would (I think) just have to return a single constant value as a hash code since any two objects *could* be equal regardless of the individual values of `fieldA` or `fieldB`.

Comment: Does that mean for this implementation of Equals where transitive property is violated as you said, when I have a list of MyClass, and I want to call list.Contains() method to find an element that matches the 'Equal', I can't use HashSet or Dictionary which gives me O(1) time complexity?

Comment: Your "Equals" would work for `Contains` but not hashing - By that definition (1,2) and (3,4) would have to have the same hash - and by extension, (5,6) would have to have the same hash (since (3,4)=(5,4)=(5,6). So _every_ object would have to have the same hash, and you'll end up with an O(N) search anyway.